# Remote desktop audio lag

Tags: windows, audio, video, remote-desktop, sync

Why when using remote desktop, when playing a video, my keyboard executions are almost perfectly in sync with the image on the screen, but the there is like a 1 second audio delay and sometimes 2 seconds.

Why can't the audio also be in sync with the image? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: To confirm, you're using Microsoft Remote Desktop (RDP)? If yes, then this application is not optimised for video playback. You need something better like ZCentral Remote Boost.

Comment: Yes its RDP, how can I setup ZCentral Remote Boost? I couldn't find a step by step guide on Youtube

Comment: ZCentral Remote Boost should be available to download on the HP website. It's free if you install it on a HP workstation, but if you choose to install it on any other device it will require a license. There are other apps out there similar to boost that offer the same low latency remote desktop solutions, such as Teredici (also by HP) however i believe it has now been re-branded as "HP Anywhere".

Comment: Alternatively, you can try enabling gpu acceleration for microsoft remote desktop via group polciy. Check out this guide: https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/kb/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-microsoft-remote-desktop/

Comment: Again, not sure if this will help due to RDP not being built for video playback purposes.